# javascript data not appending to html webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this simple code with 5 paramaters taken from an API that logs data:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        
        console.log('For Calls')
        console.log(arr[i].league.name)
        console.log(arr[i].teams.home.name, arr[i].goals.home)
        console.log(arr[i].teams.away.name, arr[i].goals.away)
}
```

it logs this data to the console (2 sets of data shown):
[Logged Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc2Xu.png)

The issue I am having is trying to display this looped content to the website, I haven't even been able to get it on the screen so far using the .append methods.

Here is the format I am trying to create:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="league">Data goes here</div>
    <div class="team1">Data goes here</div>
    <div class="score1">Data goes here</div>
    <div class="team2">Data goes here</div>
    <div class="score2">Data goes here</div>
</div>
```

I am aware I can give each div a class and append that way but I need this in a loop so those methods do not work for me in this circumstance.

Any Tips are Appreciated.

My current attempt:

```
for (i = 0; i < filtered.length-1; i++) {


    let parent = document.createElement("div")
    parent.className = 'parentDiv'
  
    let homeTeamName = document.createElement("div")
    homeTeamName.className = 'league'
    homeTeamName.innerHTML = filtered[i].league.name
    parent.appendChild(homeTeamName)
  
    let homeTeamScore = document.createElement("div")
    homeTeamScore.className = 'team1'
    homeTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i].teams.home.name
    parent.appendChild(homeTeamScore)

    let awayTeamName = document.createElement("div")
    awayTeamName.className = 'score1'
    awayTeamName.innerHTML = filtered[i].teams.home.name
    parent.appendChild(awayTeamName)

    let awayTeamScore = document.createElement("div")
    awayTeamScore.className = 'team2'
    awayTeamScore.innerHTML = filtered[i].teams.home.name
    parent.appendChild(awayTeamScore)

  
  }
```

It prints nothing to the dom, blank page. You can use the web console at footballify.net/test

Comment: Can you update the question a a runnable code snippet as a [mcve]?  You can hard-code test data to be appended to the DOM.  Though at a glance it looks like your code simply never appends `parent` to the DOM...

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the content in `arr`

Comment: You never do anything with `parent`. It's a div created in memory, with a bunch of stuff attached to it but `parent` itstelf is never attached to the DOM.

Comment: how would I attach it to the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never Attach the "parent" variable to your body

Try:

```
document.body.append(parent) at the end
```